# Add ReWrite from Old Pages to Wordpress (remove .php)

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have a WordPress site that has 4 old .php pages left to run as is.  My issue is previous there was a rewrite rule to remove the .php from the URL giving it clean URLs.

I tried just adding the same rules above and below the WordPress code in the .htaccess, but it would give a redirect loop.

```
# remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

How can I preserve access to these 4 pages using the URLs with out .php ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this lines which simply remove the `.php` from files that end with `.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! WordPress pages still work fine (w/ pretty urls) and my .php pages work without .php.